# scriptignore only take effect in the json serialization process

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

It does not affect JSON deserialization.  Any one can explain it?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If something can't be serialized, it doesn't matter whether it can or can't be deserialized because it isn't there in the data to be deserialized (see answer). An example would help yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353590.aspx) states the following:

> If you apply ScriptIgnoreAttribute to a public property or public field of a class, then JavaScriptSerializer ignores, or skips, the member when **serializing** an instance of the class to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

I take it the same holds for the JSON serializer. The documentation does not state anything concerning deserialization.

I believe the idea is that when you don't serialize a property, deserialization does not matter because the property simply isn't there in the to be deserialized data.

Comment: There is one case where it does matter: Deserialization is case-insensitive (at least for "JavScriptSerializer"). If you have two fields like "string name" and "string Name", you will get an exception.